# BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged event firing in new thread, resulting in cross-thread error in a modeless form

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

The code is supposed to;

- Find a list of strings that contain `inputStr`
- Add them to a `ToolStripDropDown` list one by one, without hanging the UI

I'm using a `BackgroundWorker` to do this, with the following code

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(e As EventArgs)
  Dim bWorker As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
  'also tried to declare bWorker in class scope - no change
  AddHandler bWorker.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
  AddHandler bWorker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
  bWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
  bWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
  'Thread is confirmed as 1
  bWorker.RunWorkerAsync(inputStr)
End Sub

Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
  Dim matchList As List(Of String) = getMatchingList(e.Argument) 'Not listed, irrelevant
  'Thread is different, as expected
  For Each lineStr In matchList
    bWorker.ReportProgress(0, lineStr)
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
  Dim lblList As Label = New Label With {.Text = e.UserState.ToString}
  Dim hstItem As ToolStripControlHost = New ToolStripControlHost(lblList)
  'Thread is different, unexpected
  toolStripControl.Items.Add(hstItem) 'This line gives me the cross-thread error, since the thread is not 1
End Sub
```

For the sake of completeness, this code is in a user control codebehind. The control is generated in run-time on a modeless form (I confirmed the thread number as 1 during the creation of the control). If I call `ShowDialog` on the form, to show it as modal, I do not suffer from this issue, but I need the form to be modeless. I tried creating the control in the form constructor, Load event and Shown event, with no change. I also tried to add the backgroundworker to the user control at design time, again with no change.

Comment: What is the value of `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` in `OnTextChanged`?

Comment: How is `ReportProgess` even called? `BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress` defaults to `false` and you have never set it to `true`. You should get an `InvalidOperationException` instead, not a cross-thread violation.

Comment: Please show the code for `Dim matchList As List(Of String) = getMatchingList(e.Argument) 'Not listed, irrelevant`.

Comment: Why is it unexpected that a handler for an event on the background worker would run on the background worker thread?  It looks to me like you need to invoke the UI updates in the event handler on the UI thread.

Comment: @Craig   [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress): *...The ProgressChanged event handler executes on the thread that created the BackgroundWorker...* -- *...The `WorkerReportsProgress` property value must be `true`, or `ReportProgress` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`...*. Thus, either `OnTextChanged` is actually rised on a thread other than the UI's, or the exception is another one.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks.  That's what I get for not reading the fine manual before commenting. :-P

Comment: @kalimag, it is 1

Comment: @Jimi, good catch. I "simplified" the code I copied here and omitted the lines that set it to true. +1

Comment: @Enigmativity, it is another subroutine that basically queries a list of strings containing some input string

Comment: @Teeracroptus - Could you please post the code for `getMatchingList`? I think it is relevant to me.

Comment: Could you also please take the code that you've posted in the question - and only that code - and paste it in to a new project, then add the controls to get it to a running state and see if you have the same error? I bet it works fine. **The code you have posted does not cause your error, so the error _must be caused by code that you haven't posted._** Please provide us with code that shows the error.